# Google Play services don't work in Internal Testing

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, android-gps, google-play-internal-testing

Auth, Achievements and leaderboards work well if I build an .apk and transfer in to a test device, but once I build a bundle for Internal testing I can't see even Authentification process.

I added my email to testers scope and I signed my bundle with a key.